# (C#) How to Change InputLanguage in .NET CF?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, .net-cf-3.5, input-language

(C#, Windows Form, .NET Compact Framework 3.5, Windows CE 6.0)

How to Change InputLanguage in .NET CF?

I want to change laguguage of UserControl keyboard.

Comment: You can change current culture at run time like System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("he-IL");

Comment: @MD's System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture can't setting at .NET CF 3.5..

Comment: What do you mean by "UserControl keyboard"? The software keyboard that is shown when you click in a textbox?

Comment: AFAIK the input language can not be changed for Windows Mobile (5, 6.x) devices. The software keyboard and the GUI are tied to the firmware build for the device. If you need to type foreign languages into C# textboxes you need a special software keyboard (see SPB software for example) and a full encoded truetype font (for example a copy of desktop arialms_unicode, see usage at http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2011/04/06/mobile-development-a-simple-unicode-character-map/).

Comment: @help you have to check which languages your CE6 image supports. If there is no support for your language you have to create an ad hoc image. If instead there is support for your language and you need to set it just as a one time configuration, you can do it from the input panel GUI.

Comment: @salvolds Two language are supported in my device. there are English and German. When I click GUI buttons, English characters are written on a textbox by Virtual-Key code. I want to write German characters on the textbox when clicking same GUI buttons. How can I change language setting?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to "Control panel"->"Regional settings" and set the input language.

See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zRQfV7C4qY).

This works if you have a persistent registry and if your GUI doesn't need to supprt multiple languages.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. I have two language in Input tab of "Regional and Langague Setting". I change default input language and reset. but there is no any change..

Comment: did you check if after the reboot the new language set was already there?

Comment: Yes, but only english language was written by keybd_event.